# Facebook Send UI renders empty window

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I was just about to test something so I made 2 buttons with 2 links:
1.) using the facebook sharer.php functionality which works fine
2.) triggering the send ui using the URL redirect I took from the FB developers homepage:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&redirect_uri=https://www.bancsabadell.com/cs/Satellite/SabAtl/

I replaced the app id and both links with my own. My app is set up so it point to the links, since I know I had it running once before, where that was the problem.

Now as said the share button works perfectly fine but when I click one the other button I just see a white screen. The URL is in the address bar. Firebug shows no console errors and an empty head and body tag.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Gerd

UPDATE: I also implemented the regular javascript ui.send method. The window popsup. I am connected with facebook as the ssl seal shows but again nothing but white.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the URL is concerned the URL is fine it is just a matter of time until Facebook allows to share a URL it has not indexed before. When I changed the link to my main domain instead of subfolder it worked.

As far as the JS SDK is concerned I forgot to check whether the user is logged in or not so this is how it works:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
    <script>      
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {        
        FB.init({          
            appId      : 'YourId',          
            xfbml      : true,          
            version    : 'v2.0'        
        });      
    };

    (function(d, s, id){         
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];         
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}         
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;         
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";         
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);       
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));    
    </script>   

  <button onclick="sendFb()">Recommend JS</button>  

<script type="text/javascript">     
    function sendFb(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                FB.ui({
                  method: 'send',
                  link: 'yourlink.com',
                });
            }
            else {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.ui({
                          method: 'send',
                          link: 'yourlink.com',
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        alert('Not Authenticated!');
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```